# Method was invoked without being called

Tags: java, methods

As you can see, the `m1()` method was not called in the main method but it prints the statement. I just want to know how the execution happened without invoking the `m1()` method.

```
class Test
{
    double a=m1();
    double m1()
    {
        System.out.println("m1() instance method invoked");
        return 100;
        

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t=new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is called here: `double a=m1();`.

Comment: You are creating the object of the class Test and the class field is getting initialized then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double a=m1();
```

This is inline initialization.

we have multiple type of initialization in java like inline,static block,non-static block,constructor:**[Initializing Fields Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)**

You're right. you have not invoked `m1()` directly but after creating a new instance of `Test`, its members get initialized. how?

java will search for inline initialization or non-static block initialization or constructor initialization .

in your code, you just have inline initialization. so java will evaluate `m1()` (invoke `m1()`) and will assign its value to your instance member `a`. so actually You have invoked `m1()` but indirectly.

Answer (score 3):

`Test`'s member `a` is initialized with a call to `m1()`. When you create an instance of `Test` (by calling `new Test()`), its members get initialized, and `m1` gets called.

Answer (score 1):

in java programming language everything starts from main function, so when you creat an instance from Test, the fields of this class are loaded and inline initialize and default constructor is called. so that's why your m1 function is called